# Problems using rsync with macOS Sonoma

Tags: rsync, macos-sonoma

I bought a new Mac mini. Before I was on Catalina. I used rsync a lot to make backups of my photos. My old scripts do not work anymore and I don't know what to do.

I am using the version of Rsync that Homebrew installs; `rsync 3.2.7_1`.

First, I have changed the location of my source directory and it has spaces in the path but I think I managed to solve this issue temporarily. I didn't manage to modify the `SOURCE_DIR` correctly and still looking how to rewrite correctly the source path.

Secondly, when I execute the script the remote server asks me for a password but it rejects it. It asks me the password even if I had copied the SSH key. I can open a SSH session without entering a password from terminal but it is not working with Rsync.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
#EXCLUSIONS="/Users/Fred/Scripts/excludePhotobackup.ini"
LOG_FILE="/Users/Fred/Logs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)_PhotoBackUp.log"
# LOG_FORMAT="%o %f %l sent %b"
#SOURCE_DIR="/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Externe/Photos/"
#SOURCE_DIR="/Volumes/Test/"
TARGET_DIR="/share/Multimedia/Photos/"
TARGET_SERVER="master@mynas.local"
# SSH="ssh -p 22"
    
rsync --protect-args -s --dry-run --archive --verbose --exclude-from=$EXCLUSIONS --log-file=$LOG_FILE --log-file-format="%o %f %l sent %b" --progress --compress --human-readable --stats -e "ssh -p 22" $SOURCE_DIR \ $TARGET_SERVER:\''/Volumes/Maci>
    
exit 0
```

Comment: FWIW, this command seems a lot more complicated than it should be. Not because of Rsync options, but because of the extra SSH stuff. You should be able to Rsync a source and destination without extra the extra SSH stuff.

Comment: Your Rsync command is still truncated at this point `$TARGET_SERVER:\''/Volumes/Maci>` so how do you expect us to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up version of your script with two different modified versions. Just note that your original Rsync command is truncated at this point `$TARGET_SERVER:\''/Volumes/Maci>` so hey; I worked around it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# EXCLUSIONS="${HOME}/Scripts/excludePhotobackup.ini";
LOG_FILE="${HOME}/Logs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)_PhotoBackUp.log";
# LOG_FORMAT="%o %f %l sent %b";
# SOURCE_DIR='"/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Externe/Photos/"';
SOURCE_DIR='"/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Externe/Photos/"';
# SOURCE_DIR='"/Volumes/Test/"';
TARGET_DIR='"/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Externe/Photos/"';
TARGET_SERVER="master@mynas.local";
SSH="ssh -p 22";

# Original query.
# echo rsync --protect-args -s --dry-run --archive --v --exclude-from=$EXCLUSIONS --log-file=$LOG_FILE --log-file-format="%o %f %l sent %b" --progress --compress --human-readable --stats -e "ssh -p 22" $SOURCE_DIR \ $TARGET_SERVER:\''/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Externe/Photos/';
# Modified version 1 with SSH.
# rsync --dry-run -savzh --progress --stats --exclude-from="${EXCLUSIONS}" --log-file="${LOG_FILE}" --log-file-format="%o %f %l sent %b" -e "${SSH} ${SOURCE_DIR} ${TARGET_SERVER}:${TARGET_DIR}";
# Modified version 2 without SSH.
rsync --dry-run -savzh --progress --stats --exclude-from="${EXCLUSIONS}" --log-file="${LOG_FILE}" --log-file-format="%o %f %l sent %b" "${SOURCE_DIR}" ${TARGET_SERVER}:"${TARGET_DIR}";

exit;
```

General cleanup items — like ending lines with a semicolon (`;`) — but mainly cleaning up Rsync.

- I compressed many of your Rsync options as `-savzh`; makes it easier to read.
- Added double quotes (`"`) to the variables in the command and braces (`{`/`}`) as well.
- Added single quotes (`'`) to the path variables; it helps avoid escaping spaces and such. Which allows the use of double-quotes inside of them.
- **Modified version 1 with SSH**: The version of your original query that uses `-e ssh`.
- **Modified version 2 without SSH**: The version of your original query that doesn’t use `-e ssh`. I favored this in my example and uncommented it because I don’t think you need that `-e ssh` at all.

Anyway, I see you posted an answer already but I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks, it really helps me.

Comment: @FredericB. Great! If the answer helped you, please be sure to upvote it. If it is the answer that solved your question, please be sure to check it off as such.

Comment: II tried your solution because I have new issues but I have strange errors.  `rsync: [sender] Failed to exec ss: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.2.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]`

Answer (score -1):

Okay so the solution was really easy for the spaces in the path, all I had to do was to add double quotes ""/path with spaces""

For the password issue it is because I messed between my source and my destination arguments.